# How do I sort a list of zip codes in an ArrayList by the top 3?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

Currently, I've got an `ArrayList` of zip codes which represent car accidents.

Ex:

```
10005
10002
10003
10005
10004
```

In this case, I would like to count the highest occurrence of each of these zip codes and sort from highest to lowest. I looked around and many people talked about using a HashMap to do this. Unfortunately, I cannot use a `HashMap` as per the directions on the homework.

What is the best way to count the frequency of each zip occurring, thus effectively counting the number of accidents per zip code without using a `HashMap`/`Hashtable`?

I've thought about doing `arrayOfZip[zipCode] = frequency` and then sorting by there, but the problem with that is that the array declared will be unnecessarily huge in memory.

Comment: So long as your question is well presented (and I believe it is), you don't need to indicate that it's a homework assignment.  It's good to know what your constraints are, though.

Comment: Are your zipcodes encapsulated in some intermediate object?

Comment: Yes. I have a collision object that keeps track of zip code, cyclist injuries and that kind of stuff. I also have a collisionList class that is an Arraylist of the collisions that I parsed from the CSV file provided.

Comment: You can use `Collections.frequency()` to get the frequency of each object in the `List`.

Answer (score 4):

You can sort the list, and then iterate through counting how long the run of each zip code is; then just keep track of the length of the 3 longest runs and their corresponding zip code.

Comment: This is good. However, if there is a tie, I also must include the tied value as well. What is the best way to keep track of this? Keep iterating past the 3rd highest and compare if the number is the same as before? Also, wouldn't this just be purely sorting through the zip codes and not the frequency?

Comment: You are sorting the zip code strings, but once they are sorted, equal elements are next to each other, so they are easy to count. Unfortunately for you, I know that this is a homework question, so I don't want to give you too many hints!

Answer (score 0):

I think Colection Frequency based methods woulb be usuful:

> int occurrences = Collections.frequency(zip, "xxxxxx");

Answer (score 0):

Sort the list and then:

```
int counter;
for(int i=0;i<SizeOfList;i+=counter)
//increment counter by no. of times a zipcode occurred to avoid repetation
    {
        counter=1;
        for(j=i+1;j<SizeOfList;++j)
            { 
                if(zipcode[i]==zipcode[j])//checking one zipcode with all next values in list
                    counter++;
            }
        System.out.print("\nFrequency of " + zipcode[i] + " is " + counter);
//getting the frequency of that zipcode and printing it(can store it if you want) 
//Next it will jump the loop by value of counter and hence
//the next zipcode inline will come into loop and it will continue till end
    }
```

This will essentially print the frequency of all unique zipcodes. You can also always compare the counter and store the highest three frequency zipcodes.